# create-react-app - installation being aborted

Tags: reactjs, npm, create-react-app

I am having a problem creating a react app using, I keep getting an error.
I am using node `v10.16.0` and npm `v 6.9.0`

I looked through many answers already and tried everything that has been suggested including reinstalling node, clearing cache etc.

I typed `npx create-react-app client`into the command prompt

and this is what I get.

```
Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts...

yarn add v1.16.0
[1/4] Resolving packages...
error Received malformed response from registry for "react". The registry may be down.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/add for documentation about this command.

Aborting installation.
  yarnpkg add --exact react react-dom react-scripts --cwd C:\Users\xxxx\Documents\Work Project\client has failed.

Deleting generated file... package.json
Deleting generated file... yarn.lock
Deleting client/ from C:\Users\xxxx\Documents\Work Project
Done.
```

Comment: use [yarn](https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/cli/add/) to install packages instead of npm

Comment: `npx create-react-app client` worked for me here just fine (same node and npm versions, but on a mac). maybe it's the network you're on? maybe try a different computer?

Comment: using yarn gives me this error `error Received malformed response from registry for "mobx-react". The registry may be down.`

Comment: seems you're mixing yarn with npm. Create a new folder, then use ONLY npx create-react-app projectname

Comment: I get the same error as written in my question above.

Comment: Have you tried uninstalling your yarn?

Comment: Thank you @azium . it was a network issue, my problem is now resolved!

Answer (score 0):

Once you have cleaned the yarn cache by running:

```
yarn cache clean
```

Removing yarn cache folder in the AppData folder as well C:\Users\test\AppData\Local\Yarn

then subsequent calls to:

```
npx create-react-app your-app
```

This works for me well